# How to access collapsed state of your quantum circuit?

Tags: qiskit

I need to be able to see the value of each qubit after measurement. I have a quantum circuit and I am measuring each qubit with measure_all, how do i see their values after this?

Answer (score 1):

To get measurement values, you need to execute the circuit. For example, here is a circuit which generates a Bell state and measures both qubits. The circuit is executed 100 times.

```
from qiskit import Aer, execute, QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.measure_all()

backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
result = execute(qc, backend, shots=100).result()
counts = result.get_counts(qc)
print(counts)
```

A sample output is

```
{'00': 53, '11': 47}
```

which corresponds to measuring $|00\rangle$ 53 out of 100 times and measuring $|11\rangle$ 47 out of 100 times.